# PdfLaTeX: Auto Wrap in a Table with Images

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Sorry to bother everyone again here! I'm trying to make a table, where it contains several images and texts, however, it cannot wrap automatically, and the table becomes a mess......

The related code is:

```
\begin{table*}[width=\textwidth,cols=3,pos=h]
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{} LLL@{} }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0    & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000000.png}$ & Training started \\
        8    & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000008.png}$ & The text is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long that not all the contents can be shown \\
        16   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000016.png}$ & \\
        32   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000032.png}$ & \\
        64   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000064.png}$ & \\
        128  & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000128.png}$ & \\
        192  & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{000192.png}$ & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}
```

And the results:

[image]

Btw, is there any solution to put the words and the images (the same row) align on the same centerline? I tried to use `\raisebox` but then images from different rows come together......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a column of fixed width, e.g. `m{3cm}` or a `tabularx` which will automatically choose the column width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l l X @{} }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0    & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & Training started \\
        8    & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & The text is too oooo oooo ooo ooo oooo oooo oooo oooo oooo oooo oooo oooo oooo ooooo ooo  long that not all the contents can be shown \\
        16   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & \\
        32   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & \\
        64   & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & \\
        128  & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & \\
        192  & $\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck}$ & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And is there any way to split the images from different rows? In this case, they are connected

Comment: @Tim If you have a new question, please ask a new question (including a [mre])